# Mounting a drive in ubuntu within a mounted directory

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I am using amazon and have elastic block stores (in all respects a NAS drive) mounted on a directory /data. Now if the NAS drive I mounted becomes full I would like to mount additional NAS drives. Now there are 2 ways of doing this:

1. Take a snapshot of the existing NAS drive. Unmount it, mount a bigger drive and copy the snap shot back in.
2. Mount an additional NAS drive.

I would like to mount an additional NAS drive to keep my cost down. I will be charged for creating and storing a snap shot. And I dont want a downtime. I am not great with linux, hence the question..

Can I mount another NAS drive inside the directory /data/abc? /data is already mounted onto NAS1.. Can I mount /data/abc onto NAS2? So all other folders would continue to exist on NAS1 and the new abc directory would point to NAS2?

If this not possible then I would probably have to mount NAS2 as /data1 and create a symlink /data/abc -> /data1

Could you guys let me know which approach is better?

Comment: this question should be moved to [superuser](http://www.superuser.com)

Answer (score 2):

> Can I mount another NAS drive inside the directory /data/abc? /

Sure